# Updating Media Library PDF's in bulk

Tags: uploads, media, ftp, pdf

I've built a new site for my client that uses PDF's from the old site media library. He's redesigned all the pdf's and now has asked me to replace them on site. It should be noted that the old PDFs a technical product data that have been built up over the years - they are attached to specific products within the product catalogue.

How do i exchange these files in bulk? Ideally I'd like to overwrite the old PDF's with the new, but because the old ones have been created over the years, they live in many different folders.

I was wondering if there was a function in filezilla or something that would leave the folder structure alone but allow me to overwrite the files using just their filenames?

ie replace

datasheet.pdf
with
datasheet-new.pdf

Many thanks in advance

Comment: note that the media library is not a file/folder browser, attachments/uploads are posts in the database, so you can't do this via Filezilla if you want new filenames. You would need to upload the new PDFs then attach them to the posts. I do not believe there is a simple method of doing this, and to automate it there are some unanswered questions about your datasheets, e.g. given a new PDF xyz.pdf, how do you know which PDF it's meant to replace and which post to update? And does that work for _all_ of them or just _most_ of them?

Comment: Also are these uploaded to WP or are they just dumped in a folder of your own creation then linked to?

Comment: Yeah attaching them post-by-post is what I'm trying to avoid doing if possible, It's perfectly okay to use the same filenames if that gives me a solution. I was hoping there was a plugin perhaps that would expose all the PDF's in the media library and all ow me to overwrite them if the filenames are the same - kind of the same way you can do with Windows.

Comment: Uploaded to WP yes

Comment: even if there was a plugin that gave you exactly what you wanted, asking for it would mean closing your question as recommendations are offtopic here. Likewise any answers that try to recommend a product would get downvoted of flagged. If it's a recommendation you want, you should ask on the software recommendations stack

Comment: also if you want the same filenames, you can just upload over the top of the old files. Doing that shouldn't involve any WordPress questions though, and would be an unrelated Filezilla support question and off-topic here.